# Why do JS frameworks use inline styling instead of CSS for layouting

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, dojo

Looking at various JS frameworks (Dojo, Ext.JS, and others) i have observed that layouting is often, if not always, done via direct DOM manipulation, as in setting inline styles on a given DOM element/s.
This contrasts starkly with what CSS tries to aim, and it appears to me that often CSS is only left to "prettify" such scenarios, dictating colors and the like.

I would like to understand why this choice has been made, perhaps even from a historical point of view, and your choice of CSS or inline styling for the layout part of a page/webapplication.

In what case would you be comfortable using ONLY CSS via a stylesheet without using js dom manipulation?
What case would speak for the opposite?

Thanks!

Comment: Inline styles are CSS too. I suppose you mean direct DOM properties modification.

Comment: yes i mean direct dom style attribute modification, and yes, i'm aware its CSS too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they use math to position things for the most part and CSS Calc isn't well supported.

For example in jQuery UI they use math to figure out where a dialog box should go on the screen or how to split columns up.

CSS is catching up with things like [Flexbox](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/) and [Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc), but the JS frameworks you mentioned often support very old browsers like IE6 which won't EVER be getting these CSS updates.

Comment: good answer, i think you meant "but these frameworks often **do not** support very old browsers like IE6."

Comment: @jbabey - No. The large frameworks very often **do** support very old browsers, in part to fill in the gaps in CSS support.

Comment: [sencha person] Jamund is correct, Ext JS uses Math to do stuff that more recent CSS (flexbox, position:fixed etc.) can do automatically. We also have to work all the way back to IE6, so doing our own Math is the only solution for now. Sencha Touch 2 - our most recent mobile browser framework uses CSS layout much more heavily because we don't have legacy issues

Answer (score 3):

There are different reasons for this behavior.

1. If you wouldn't want to use direct DOM manipulation you would need to write your new rules into a physical css file and then load the file as a dependency for the page. Much too complicated and totally unneeded.
2. Inline styling is not CSS?
3. Manipulation via front-end scripting must be inline, to make sure that the new styles have a higher rank than the original defined ones.